# If function has an absolute maximum at interior point, then it it not injective

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need some help to understand proof of exercise. So we have

Let $I:=[a,b]$ and $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be continuous on $I$. If $f$ has an absolute maximum at an interior point $c$ of $I$, then $f$ is not injective on $I$.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ If $f$ has an absolute maximum at $c \in (a,b)$ and $f$ is injective, then $f(a)<f(c)$ and $f(b)<f(c)$. Either $f(a)\leq f(b)$ or $f(b)<f(a)$. In the first case, either $f(a)=f(b)$ or $f(a)<f(b)$. If $f(a)=f(b)$, but $a\neq b$ we have a contradiction. But I have a problem with the second case. If $f(a)<f(b)$ then $f(a)<f(b)<f(c)$, $\textbf{whence there exists $b'\in (a,c)$ with $f(b')=f(b)$}$. But why can not $b'$ equal to $b$, since we have assumption that $f$ is injective. How do we get a contradiction here?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b'$ cannot equal $b$ because $b'$ is an element of $(a,c)$, meaning $b'<c$. Combine that with the fact that $c<b$, and you get $b'<b$, threfore, $b'\neq b$.

Answer (score 2):

You may use also the fact,  if you like, that if $f$ is continuous and injective then it should be strictly monotonous. But the last cannot happen as $f$ has local extremum inside $(a,b)$.